# How to use Spark SQL in a multi-thread enviroment with Spring and RabbitMQ?

Tags: java, spring, apache-spark, rabbitmq

I inherited a Java code that uses Spark for XML processing. It doesn't do anything special with it, it just loads the XML and creates a dataset from the tags necessary for the processing.

The problem is, the code that starts the Spark session, loads the file and creates the dataset are running on a Spring RabbitMQ consumer queue thread. Every time the queue receives a message, it recreates the spark session, a process that is somewhat time-consuming.

The code is something like this:

```
    FileProcessing fileProcessing = fileProcessingRepo.findById(id).get();

    SparkSession sparkSession = SparkSession.builder().master("local").config("spark.executor.memory", "1g")
            .config("spark.driver.memory", "1g").config("spark.memory.offHeap.enabled", true)
            .config("spark.memory.offHeap.size", "3g").appName("xmlProcessing").getOrCreate();

    HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
    params.put("rowTag", SOME_TAG);
    Dataset<Row> dfXML = sparkSession.read().format("com.databricks.spark.xml").options(params)
            .load(fileProcessing.getFileFormS3());

    doPartOneOfTheProcessing(dfXML);

    params.put("rowTag", SOME_OTHER_TAG);
    dfXML = sparkSession.read().format("com.databricks.spark.xml").options(params)
            .load(fileProcessing.getFileFormS3());
    dfXML.show(10000);
    doPartTwoOfTheProcessing(dfXML);

    sparkSession.close();
```

This in running inside a component managed by Spring, called from a Spring RabbitMQ queue consumer.

My question is, aside removing the duplicate XML file loading from Spark, what's the best way to handle the Spark session inside a Spring/RabbitMQ enviroment? Should I let Spring manage the SparkSession creation? What part of the process of SparkSession creation is thread-safe and could potentially be optmized in a multi-thread environment?

Comment: I think you can create the SparkSession as part of you Spring Initializer and use Depedency injection(auto wire) to use it across other components.. SparkSession should be available till your lifecycle of your application..